# Regex for input type="number" prevent enter plus character

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a Regex for validation input type="number" but the problem with my regex that it allows to enter plus character, how to prevent enter plus symbol, but allow to enter minus? For example you can enter: 123; 11,22; -33; -33.44 but not allowed enter +123 and -0, +0

```
const deprecatedKeys = /^-+?\D$|^decimal$|^multiply$|^add$|^divide$|^subtract$|^spacebar$/i;
```

Comment: Not so simple. You allow `+?` but also have `\D` which includes `+`. Additionally, the caret could be put at the start and use a non-capturing group afterwards. Please add some more information and allowed inputs.

Comment: What do you want to match with `^-+?\D$`. It currently would match an hyphen between one and unlimited times but as few as possible and a non-digit character. So stuff like `-----+` would match too.

Comment: ^-+?\D$ - I did it for allowed enter minus symbol and digital

Comment: A digit you mean? So `^-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 1st part of your current pattern is problematic: `^-+?\D$` would currently match an hyphen between one and unlimited times but as few as possible and a non-digit character. So stuff like '-----+' or '-X' would match too.

If you want to allow for an optional leading hyphen and optional decimals, you could use:

```
^(?!-0$)-?\d+(?:[.,]\d+)?$
```

Furthermore, all these alternations could be grouped in a non-capture group with a single leading and trailing anchor:

```
^(?:(?!-0$)-?\d+(?:[.,]\d+)?|decimal|multiply|add|divide|subtract|spacebar)$
```

Comment: regex this allow enter plus symbol

Comment: No it [doesn't](https://regex101.com/r/nmQM1g/1) @dmytro90